# Is it safe to convert a std::wstring to cstring?

Tags: c++, openframeworks

***To clarify, I'm not overly concerned about data-loss*** as this is for logging actions inside my application and I'm using wstring as the primary data type. Due to the nature of the frameworks I'm currently using (OpenFrameworks logging which is `std::string` by default and I'm fine with that).

Here's an example of my current conversion:

```
//ofLog.h--patch | `message` is a `std::ostringstream`
    ofLog& operator<<(const std::wstring& value){
        message << value.c_str() << padding;
        return *this;
    }
```

By using this specific overload I can save myself a lot of annoyance in the Verbose logs and not worry too much if I have third party std::strings (OSC(char) libraries vs JSON(wchar) libraries for example).

I'm relatively new to C++ having lived in a Java/JavaScript world and I'm just wondering if there's anything other than potential data-loss at risk here. Are there are platform-independent solutions to this problem? I've been Googling for several hours and I want to have a "safe" solution that won't bite me down the road.

Basically my solution appears to work, but I want to know if there are potential issues down the road by doing this.

Thanks!
*(the openframeworks tag is just to help people down the road if we solve it)*

**EDIT**
If anyone needs this for OpenFrameworks the following seems to work for me:

```
/*
ofLog.h
*/
        /// \brief Overload the wstring operator so that this actually works for 
        /// data of that format
        ///
        ofLog& operator<<(const std::wstring& value){
            std::string cvalue;
            std::transform(value.begin(), value.end(), 
                std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>(cvalue),
                [](wchar_t wide) 
                {
                    return static_cast<char>(wide > 127 ? '?' : wide);
                });

            message << cvalue << padding;
            return *this;
        }

        /// \brief Overloaded to support wchar_t * types
        ///
        /// 
        ofLog& operator<<(const wchar_t* value)
        {
            std::wstring wstr(value);
            std::string cvalue;
            std::transform(wstr.begin(), wstr.end(),
                std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>(cvalue),
                [](wchar_t wide)
            {
                return static_cast<char>(wide > 127 ? '?' : wide);
            });

            message << cvalue << padding;
            return *this;
        }
//END ofLog.h
```

Comment: Do you expect your `wstring` to consist mostly of US-ASCII content?

Comment: Yes, I suspect it will nearly always be ASCII for critical information

Comment: for std::wstring::c_str(), it returns const wchar_t*；however, std::ostringstream doesn't have an operator<< overload taking const wchar_t* as the argument; It probably chooses operator<<(void*), for which maybe not what your want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shown code is not going to work correctly. `std::wstring`'s `c_str()` method returns a `const wchar_t *`. Passing it to `std::ostringstream`'s `operator<<` will choose the `operator<<` overload that takes `const void *` parameter, which will not accomplish anything useful.

You stated that you expect your `std::wstring` to consist mostly of US-ASCII characters. If so, the hackiest approach is to rudely convert the `std::wstring` to a `std::string`, in the following manner, replacing all non-ASCII characters with a question mark (or pick your favorite punctuation symbol):

```
std::string cvalue;

std::transform(value.begin(), value.end(),
               std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>(cvalue),
               [](wchar_t wchar)
               {
                     return static_cast<char>(wchar > 127 ? '?':wchar);
               });
```

Proceed, and `<<` the ordinary `std::string` into your `message`.

If you expect your wide string to consist mostly of US-ASCII content, this would be a quick hack to get the job done. Otherwise, one would need to use the localization library to properly convert the wide string to a narrow character string using the current system locale. Quite a bit of work...

Comment: Thanks Sam, is there a possibility I could dig up a conversion in the boost libraries or another common library as a reference point? In the meantime a "hack" seems fine for this project.

Comment: If your implementation uses unicode for its wide characters, and your locale character set is the very reasonable `UTF-8`, I'll just give a plug to [my own Unicode library](http://www.courier-mta.org/unicode/unicode__iconvert__fromu.html).

Comment: I suppose converting to UTF-8 would be better than throwing the high values away

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely helpful. Ideally I will probably try to patch the OpenFrameworks log to use wchar support by default and convert the other direction (which should be much safer) but this will get me through the rough right now.